# Initiate ipdb from Vim in another ConEmu Tab

Tags: vim, conemu

Struggling to initiate another ConEmu Tab from Vim

My procedure was:

1. Vim is started from ConEmu
2. Issue a command from Vim to open new tab and start ipdb.

My idea was:

```
:silent !ConEmu.exe /cmd {Something here to initiate python -m ipdb %?} -new_console:s
```

But no success.

With this command:

```
:silent !ConEmu.exe /cmd -new_console:s
```

Another Tab is open with following message -
[ConEmuC: Root process was alive less that 10 sec, ExitCode=1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enD0f.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to do simply

```
:silent !start python -m ipdb
```

Also read `:h :!start`

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was not exactly what I asked for (although, it was not clearly stated in my question) - but it helped. It is opening layered window and I wanted to have side by side with my vim. But, hurray for me also, I managed with your hint to make it at last:

```
:silent !start cmd.exe /c -new_console:s python -m ipdb %
```

This command is opening new tab side by side with vim

Here is what I did in _vimrc:

```
"python with virtualenv support                                                                                        
let pipenv_venv_path = system('pipenv --venv')                                                                         
" The above system() call produces a non zero exit code whenever                                                       
" a proper virtual environment has not been found.                                                                     
if shell_error == 0                                                                                                    
  let venv_path = substitute(pipenv_venv_path, '\n', '', '')                                                           
  let py_binary = venv_path . '/Scripts/python.exe'                                                                    
else                                                                                                                   
  let py_binary = 'python.exe'                                                                                         
endif                                                                                                                  

"map F10 to execute ipdb in separate split Tab in ConEmu:                                                              
nnoremap <silent> <expr> <F10> '<ESC>:w!<CR>:!start cmd.exe /c -new_console:s ' . expand(py_binary)  . ' -m ipdb %<CR>'
```

Thanks for your help!